# How to load STDIN for a backtick in perl (without writing to a temp file)

Tags: windows, perl, stdout, stdin, backticks

I'm executing a system command, and wanting to (1) pre-load STDIN for the system command and (2) capture the STDOUT from the command.

Per [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) I see I can do this:

```
open(SPLAT, "stuff")   || die "can't open stuff: $!";
open(STDIN, "<&SPLAT") || die "can't dupe SPLAT: $!";
print STDOUT `sort`;
```

This uses the currently defined STDIN as STDIN for the sort. That's great if I have the data in a file, but I have it in a variable. Is there a way I can load the contents of the variable into STDIN before executing the system command? Something like:

```
open(STDIN, "<$myvariable"); # I know this syntax is not right, but you get the idea
print STDOUT `sort`;
```

Can this be done without using a temp file? Also, I'm in Windows, so Open2 is not recommended, I hear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason not to use `open2` on Windows. That said, `open2` and `open3` are rather low-level interfaces, so they're usually not the best choice on any platform.

Better alternatives include [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run) and [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run3). IPC::Run is a bit more powerful than IPC::Run3, but the latter is a bit simpler to use.

May I recommend

```
use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );
my $stdin = ...;
run3([ 'sort' ], \$stdin, \my $stdout);
```

It even does error checking for you.

---

But since you mentioned `open2`,

```
use IPC::Open2 qw( open2 );
my $stdin =...;
my $pid = open2(\local *TO_CHILD, \local *FROM_CHILD, 'sort');
print TO_CHILD $stdin;
close TO_CHILD;
my $stdout = '';
$stdout .= $_ while <FROM_CHILD>;
waitpid($pid);
die $? if $?;
```

Comment: Thanks. I really like the simplicity of `Run3`, especially since I'm not needing a bunch of functionality. Very compact.

Comment: do you happen to know if ActiveState has an equivalent to IPC::Run3? I don't see it in their ppm listing. Maybe it's the `IPC::Cmd` ?

Comment: Either it does or it doesn't. A different module isn't equivalent. That said, it IS available in AS's 5.14.2 32-bit repo, and you could always install it using `cpan IPC::Run3`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `IPC::Open2` didn't work so well on Windows 15 years ago, but I wouldn't expect you to have any trouble with it now.

```
use IPC::Open2;
my $pid = open2( \*SORT_OUT, \*SORT_IN, 'sort' );
print SORT_IN $sort_input;  # or  @sort_input
close SORT_IN;
print "The sorted output is: ", <SORT_OUT>;
close SORT_OUT;
```

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight on the usability of Open2 on Windows. Good answer. +1.